# Use a image from a server in Django template

Tags: javascript, django, python-3.x

Right now I'm storing the image in the static folder, but this is not working in production.

**View**

```
local_path = "checkimage/static/{}".format(image_file_name)
download_blob(server_path, path + '/' + image_file_name, local_path)
```

**javascript**

```
let img = '<img  src="/static/' + image_file_name + '/>';
```

Which is the correct approach to do this? They are several images and very heavy.

Comment: How are you serving your static files in production? [Whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/)?

Comment: @wcarhart Whitenoise, was the only way to get it working

Comment: Does the image work as expected locally? If so, is your image file in `staticfiles/`, or just in `app_name/static/` (on the production server)?

Comment: @wcarhart works perfectly, is app_name/static/

Comment: Hmm, so when you run in production, you need to move all of your static files to a specified location. The default for Django is `staticfiles/`. There's a helpful Django command to do this: `python manage.py collectstatic`

Comment: You'll have to do that on the production server location, via `ssh` or whatever is appropriate

Comment: @wcarhart That's done, and everything works fine, the problem is with the new images that I need to download and display

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199333/discussion-between-wcarhart-and-exsnake).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than downloading a static file from another website, you can just access the image via HTML in your template file:

```
<img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/rl0FOxdz7CcxO/giphy.gif" alt="gif of someone celebrating, with text 'It's happening'">
```

If, for whatever reason, you don't want to access the image file in your template and you still want to download it, you'll need to move the downloaded file to `staticfiles/` or to wherever you've configured your static files to be served from in `settings.py`. Putting the static file in `app_name/static/` will not work in production.

Answer (score 0):

If your image is part of a model's fields (ie ImageField) or uploaded, django sets up an url attribute to get the url of the image.

```
class ModelName(models.Model):
     image = models.ImageField(upload_to='folder_name/')
     ...
```

Pass data with your views.
In your template:

```
let img = '<img  src="{{data.image.url}}"/>';
```

And Do not forget to add this i settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```